# display a custom value from added database table in product view

Tags: magento2

I have created a module who I create too table for alternate group price & alternate client price :

```
id | client_id | product_id | price
 5 |    24     |    84      | 45

id | group_id | product_id  | price
 0 |    1     |    20       |  20
```

My table are full but I fail to display the value on product front view I don't know who to process. I understand I need to override the phtml and maybe the controller but I always found for create a new controller not for override existent.

```
<?php 
namespace miaou\CreateTable\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $table = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($installer->getTable('prix_client_conseil'))
            ->addColumn(
                'entity_id',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'ID'
            )
              ->addColumn(
                'user_id',
                Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'User ID'
            )
              ->addColumn(
                'product_id',
                Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'Product ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'prix',
                Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                'prix'

            )
            ->setComment('Prix conseillé pour un article par client');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $table2 = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($installer->getTable('prix_groupe_conseil'))
            ->addColumn(
                'entity_id',
                Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'ID'
            )
              ->addColumn(
                'groupe_id',
                Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'Proupe ID'
            )
              ->addColumn(
                'product_id',
                Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'Product ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'prix',
                Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                'prix'

            )
            ->setComment('Prix conseillé pour un article par groupe');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table2);        

        $installer->endSetup();
    }

}
```

I have also created the Collection file and Model Resource

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution founded,

Need a complete functional module.

RootName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">            
            <block class="RootName/ModuleName\Block\Features" name="RootName_Features" after="-" template="RootName_ModuleName::textblock.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

RootName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/textblock.phtml

```
<?php
$features = $block->getFeatures();

?>
<div>
    <pre>
        <?php
        var_dump($features);       
        ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

RootName/ModuleName/Block/Features.php

```
<?php

namespace RootName\ModuleName\Block;

class Features extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_product = null;
    protected $_registry;
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup,
            array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;        
        $this->_customerGroup = $customerGroup;       
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout() {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getFeatures() {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $result = array();

            $table = $resource->getTableName('');

            $sql = "";
            $result[] = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 

        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```